# In 'corrupt' countries, what proportion of government funds get spent on what they are allocated?

Tags: fiscal-policy, national-accounts

Are there any estimates across countries of the proportion of funds that actually get spent on what they're allocated to be spent on?<sup>1</sup>

Most OECD countries would probably have ratios *close* to 1:1, that is, most of the money allocated to a particular purpose gets spent on that purpose. However countries with more corruption may have much worse ratios.

I tried exploring some global [corruption](https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/2020) indices but couldn't find anything on this particular aspect, although I came across anecdotal stories (quite a few of them).

<sup>1</sup> Through econometric analysis, construction of indices, literature review, meta studies, or otherwise.